# I would like to post a good review for this plugin, but its not allowing me?

Tags: magento-2.0, review

https://marketplace.magento.com/ebizmarts-magento2-magemonkey.html

Anyone here can help me on how to post a good review for this team.
I cannot post a review.

Comment: maybe write an email to magento marketplace contact

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: review form is not showing at all :)

Comment: This should be directed to marketplace@magento.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer can only review products that were purchased on Marketplace.  The process is in the following steps:

1. A notification email is sent after purchase.
2. Email prompt to write a review. Sender is [noreply@magento.com](http://mailto:noreply@magento.com)
3. Click "write a review."
4. Complete the review.
5. Submit the review.
6. Marketplace team reviews the context(usually it will take up to 72 hours).
7. The review is posted to the product page.

See the screenshot of a review email.

**[image]**